# Google sheets IF with multiple conditions

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

This works fine, meaning it applies to the entire column.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(J:J > TODAY(), DATEDIF(TODAY(),J:J,"D"), "x"))
```

But I want to exclude the first J row which is not a date, I need to add AND so it becomes

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(ISDATE(J:J), J:J > TODAY()), DATEDIF(TODAY(),J:J,"D"), "x"))
```

and now it doesn't work anymore and the entire column is empty

So how to make ARRAYFORMULA work with multiple conditions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` and `OR` are not supported within `ARRAYFORMULA`

try:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IF((IFERROR(DATEVALUE(J:J)))*(J:J > TODAY()), 
  DATEDIF(TODAY(), J:J, "D"), "x"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Doesn't work. But I found on google that the issue is that ISDATE does not work inside ARRAYFORMULA. seems to be a bug that is not being fixed for years